# Concentration of random Rayleigh quotients

Tags: pr.probability, kernels

Let $K$ be some large square matrix of height $N$, and $u$ a column vector of height $N$. Fixing $n$, take a random set of $n$ indices (with replacement) uniformly from $1,...,N$. Let $y$ be the restriction of $u$ to those indices and $H$ the principal submatrix obtained by deleting every row and column *not* of those indices. Now consider the Rayleigh quotient

$$\frac{y^THy}{y^Ty} \tag 1$$

Empirical evidence suggests that this quantity is concentrated around its mean and roughly "independent" of $y^Ty$, that is, $y^THy$ is essentially an affine function of $y^Ty$. Here are some plots (using two different big vectors $u$):

[image]

I'm interested in proving that this is the case. Ultimately what I would like is to obtain concentration bounds for the Rayleigh quotient $(1)$. A naive approach would be to bound the numerator and denominator separately, however this gives very poor bounds on the slope when the two are highly correlated as they appear to be, hence my interest in understanding the correlation.

The quantity $u^TKu$ is a sum of $N^2$ values, and $y^THy$ is the sum of a random subset of $n^2$ of those values, so that $\frac1{n^2}y^THy$ is a biased estimator for $\frac1{N^2}u^TKu$. So understanding the distribution and concentration of that quantity seems tractable to me, however, once you normalize by the random $y^Ty$ I'm not sure what tools to use.

The only paper considering a similar problem that I'm aware is Section 3 of [Cristianini et al. (2001)](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/1946-on-kernel-target-alignment.pdf). However, they make the assumption that $u$ consists only of the values $1$ and $-1$, making $y^Ty$ fixed and equal to $n$, basically completely side-stepping precisely what I think is the hard part of the problem.

Comment: Does $K$ have any particular structure? Is it a random matrix (eg., GOE)?

Comment: @SteveHuntsman Symmetric positive definite.